# Axios GET request only works on /search but not /random on Tenor API

Tags: typescript, axios

I'm trying to fetch `/random` on Tenor API, the URL works on the browser but not with my code.

I'm pretty sure my code works because I tried using the same code on the `/search` endpoint and it works.

Here's my current `/random` endpoint code

```
import axios from "axios";

type Result = {
  media: Array<{
    gif: {
      url: string;
    };
  }>;
};

type Results = {
  results: Result[];
};

export default async function getPadoru() {
  const res = await axios.get<Results>(
    // works on the browser
    `https://g.tenor.com/v1/random?q=padoru&key=LIVDSRZULELA&limit=10&media_filter=minimal`
  );

  await console.log(res);

  return await res;
}
```

This code with this end point get me this

[image]

Unlike when I use the URL with the `/search` endpoint which gives me the correct data.

`https://g.tenor.com/v1/search?q=padoru&key=LIVDSRZULELA&limit=10&media_filter=minimal`

[image]

Comment: I ran your code against the `/random` endpoint and it works fine for me.  Your problem lies elsewhere and have not posted enough information.

Comment: I was making a discord bot https://github.com/PathonScript/PadoruBot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it's a problem with the current axios version of `1.2.0`. I downgraded it to `1.1.3` and it works now